# rand() generator stuck on 1 number c++

Tags: c++

Im writing a code with a function that return a random number. the random number is generated from 0 to maximum number that I entered. beside that I have to generate 3 random number, then the random number will return char '-' '+' '*' instead. The code doesn't work properly. whenever I put 100, the random number generated is always 41 and the other random that generated char always generate - sign with smiley face (not kidding, theres a smiley face appear next to the char sign). Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?  Thank you so much for help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int getNumber(int);
    char getOperator(int);
    int max = 0;
    int randOperator = 0;

    cout << "Enter a value(1- 101)" << endl;
    cin >> max;

    while((max < 0) || (max > 101))
    {
        cout << "invalid value. Please enter a value (1 - 101)" << endl;
        cin >> max;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << getNumber(max) << endl;

    cout << getOperator(randOperator);


}

int getNumber(int max)
{
    int hehe;
    hehe = rand()% max;
    return hehe;
}

char getOperator(int randOperator)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        randOperator = rand() % 3;

        if(randOperator = 0)
        {
            cout << '+';
        }else if(randOperator = 1)
        {
            cout << '-';
        }else
        {
            cout << '*';
        }

        return randOperator;
    }
}
```

Comment: seed your `rand` with `srand()`. You can just search for it in Google. You'll get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This code should fix your problems

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int getNumber(int);
    char getOperator(int);
    int max = 0;
    int randOperator = 0;

    cout << "Enter a value(1- 101)" << endl;
    cin >> max;

    while((max < 0) || (max > 101))
    {
        cout << "invalid value. Please enter a value (1 - 101)" << endl;
        cin >> max;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << getNumber(max) << endl;

    cout << getOperator(randOperator);


}

int getNumber(int max)
{
    int hehe;
    hehe = rand()% max;
    return hehe;
}

char getOperator(int randOperator)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        randOperator = rand() % 3;

        if(randOperator == 0)
        {
            return '+';
        }else if(randOperator == 1)
        {
            return '-';
        }else
        {
            return '*';
        }

    }
}
```

To generate different random numbers each time you run your program, you need to seed the `rand()`. You can do this by using `srand()` as I have used in this code.

A careless error you made was

```
if(randOperator = 0)
```

and

```
else if(randOperator = 1)
```

If you look closely, you will see that you have used `=` instead of `==` to check for equality. `=` will assign values, so to check for equality, use `==` as indicated in my code.

Now in this part of your code

```
char getOperator(int randOperator)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        randOperator = rand() % 3;

        if(randOperator = 0)
        {
            cout << '+';
        }else if(randOperator = 1)
        {
            cout << '-';
        }else
        {
            cout << '*';
        }

        return randOperator;
    }
}
```

The return type of the function is char and you are returning an int. In my code, instead of using `cout << '+';`, I have used `return '+';`. By doing this, the operator is returned as you wished.

Well, this is it for the explanation. If you need more explanation, then just ask.

Comment: @DownVoter, It would be best if you gave a reason for the downvote. Only then will I be able to correct it.

Comment: I hate that too. Downvote without comment. I vote you up.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, if you don't then how am I supposed to know what the problem with my answer is ? If you notify me of the problem, then I will be able to correct it and also not repeat it in the future. It is in this way, that we are able to improve ourselves.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, yeah, it sure is. If we are not allowed to tell others of their mistake, then how will newbies be able to post answers the correct way ?

Comment: @ArunA.S: We're allowed to write comments on an answer obviously and to point out problems. But we're not allowed to indicate that the feedback is linked to a downvote. Which is just bizarre. When I get a downvote I want to know _why the downvote_, i.e. "-1: because...."

Comment: So we can comment on mistakes in an answer but we cannot explain or give a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I don't actually mind a down-vote if I deserved it ( nor do I wan't to know who down-voted ), but I would rather prefer a comment if there's something wrong with my post. Well thanks for your support. I didn't know of such a rule.

Comment: BTW I didn't downvote

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, like I said, I don't care who down-voted. If I deserved it for my answer, then that's my fault ( I would never hold a grudge against anyone ). I would just prefer a comment if possible. Anyway, thanks again for your support.

Comment: I am not a Computer Science major, I just need this class as prerequisite for Engineering major. I also never take programming class in high school. Regardless whether the answer you guys give me is right or wrong, I really appreciate the time and effort you guys put into my question and give me the solutions.

Comment: @NumbNuts, Happy to be of help. If you need more info about why I have made the program so, just ask...   :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs:

First bug:
In your function getOperator you assign a value in the `if` statement not check for equality! For that you have to use `==`.

As a result, you get always '-' as result. Because `randOperator=1` has 1 as result wich is true.

```
 char getOperator(int randOperator)
 {
    for(int x =0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        randOperator = rand() % 3;

        if(randOperator == 0) //!!!!! You used (randOperator = 0) which will be interpreted as false
        {
            cout << '+';
        }else if(randOperator == 1) // !!!!!! You used (randOperator = 1) which will be interpreted as true
        {
            cout << '-';
        }else
        {
            cout << '*';
        }

        return randOperator;
    }
}
```

The second bug (smiley)

You put out the operator and give back the value of rand (the smiley) this is covered by a `for` which is only run once (because of the return)?!

Try this instead:

```
 char getOperator(int randOperator)
 {
        randOperator = rand() % 3;

        if(randOperator == 0) //!!!!! You used (randOperator = 0) which will be interpreted as false
        {
            return '+';
        }else if(randOperator == 1) // !!!!!! You used (randOperator = 1) which will be interpreted as true
        {
            return '-';
        }
        return '*';
}
```

still ugly like hell, but it will work.

Comment: apparently we should not add << after return statement. just type return '+' or whatever char.

Comment: @NumbNuts Sorry typo (the good old copy&past errors) :-)

Comment: thanks. it works now. The only problem I have now is how to fix the general rand() on my regular random number generator. should I use srand() instead of rand(). Because rand() % max never generate different number whenever I put max = 100.

Comment: @NumbNuts, actually you need to use both, `srand()` just seeds the `rand()`, to put it in simpler words, by using `srand()` before `rand()`, you will be able to produce different values. Check my answer, it shows how.